# Puppet task command does not return output

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

During executing **Puppet task run  --nodes ip** command i get reports/logs for most of the servers but only for a single server i get "**no output for this node** ".Even changes are not reflected in that machine while the same command works for rest of the machines.But at the same time job is not failed,it succeeds.

Note: I have a .sh file inside module/tasks/init.sh which contains **puppet agent -t --tags (i pass parameters)** command in it.Upon executing puppet task run command,puppet agent -t will be ran on those machines.

What will be the cause and is there anything not allowing to run that .sh file?

Update:
tasks module -  modulename/tasks/init.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
puppet agent -t --noop --tags $PT_class --environment=$PT_env
```

Command to be executed in master: 
puppet task run task_module_name class=modulename env=staging --query 'inventory { trusted.extensions.certname = "fqdn"}'

When in run this commadn it gets executed successfully but tasks module is not executed on agent machine

Note: I face this only on CIS hardening AMI on AWS

Comment: You've presented no code and no information about any characteristics of the troublesome node.  Consequently, we have no way to evaluate the situation or to meaningfully answer the question.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Kindly check my update above

Comment: @JohnBollinger Also this is not working only on  amazon linux machine while it is working on centos

Comment: Does the command `puppet agent -t --noop --tags modulename --environment=staging` produce output for the affected node when you run it directly at the command line?

Comment: Note that the `puppet agent` command you are running is a bit suspicious: do you understand that the `--tags` option does not *add* any classes or resources to the transaction, but rather *filters out* classes and resources that otherwise would be included, but which do not bear any of the specified tags?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes,if i run in that specific node it gets executed and i can get logs...while i run puppet task run command from master...this specific node returns only "no output for this node" output.....Its strange for me as it happens only on a specific machine.